# Retrieving and saving data

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Need some help to understand below sample code to connect and retreive data from database usind odbc.  i do understand sql query.. thats not an issue

```
 function getObject($query, $params, &$output)
        {
            global $connect;
            $result = odbc_prepare($connect, $query);
            odbc_execute($result, $params);

            $j=0;

            while($object = odbc_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $output[$j++] = $object;
            }
        }



    function _getDeviceByIdentification($identification)
        {
            $query =
                "SELECT * FROM Device"
                ." WHERE Identification = ?'".$identification."'";
            $params = array(
                    $identification);
            getObject($query, $params, $ret);
            return $ret;
```

Comment: @chris85 Seems like someone hasn't understood prepared statements there. Or at least, I don't understand it neither what OP is trying to do there

Comment: can u please explain me . thats part of code i dont understand apart from sql query.  details explanation would be highly appreciated

Comment: @tomtom I've added more details to my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect. Don't pass the value in the query, that is what the placeholder `?` is for.

```
function _getDeviceByIdentification($identification) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Device WHERE Identification = ?";
    $params = array($identification);
    getObject($query, $params, $ret);
    return $ret;
```

The driver swaps the placeholder `?` with the value (whatever `$identification` contains) and escapes any characters that are special.

So for example say you had `$identification = "olde' iphone";`. Passing that to the query directly:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM Device WHERE Identification = '$identification'";
```

would make an incorrect query because it comes out as:

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE Identification = 'olde' iphone';
                                                 ^ string closed, the rest of the query is unexpected
```

however when the driver sees the `'` it knows to escape it.

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE Identification = 'olde\' iphone';
```

so the `'` isn't an encapsulation character anymore.

The `$params = array($identification);` makes an array of terms that map to the placeholders (they map in the order they are presented in the array, and the order the fall in the query). If you follow the code execution you can see the array ends up being used in the http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php (which is what actually does the binding).

Comment: can u tell me use of that part of code .  $params = array(
                    $identification);

Comment: @tomtom I've updated the answer a bit more. Let me know if that makes sense.